# partition by 3 column and found max

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this table :

[image]

I need to find the deal description with the max amount for each customer every year.
I don't know if I should use over partition or not.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window function :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by custmerid, year(datedeal) order by dealamount desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With ROW_NUMBER() window function:

```
select t.customerid, t.dateofdeal, t.dealdesription, t.dealamount
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by customerid, year(dateofdeal) order by dealamount desc) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```